# "Disable type-checking" stopped working after ts-jest upgrade to 29.0

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, typechecking

With 29.0 ts-jest deprecated setting ts-jest-options via the globals property in the jest config file. Instead one should use the transform property as described in https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/options/isolatedModules.
Neither the old way nor the new way seems to disable type-checking...
Is this a bug introduced with ts-jest 29.0?

Comment: Also impacted. We have around 900 files generated from a few API Swagger docs using OpenAPI generator and type checking these for every test (suite?) caused our tests to run extremely slowly. As part of the version update, we converted the global config as directed however this does not appear to have any affect as the tests are now taking multiple minutes to complete and melting my CPU.